# tesseract error - Image too large

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract

I am getting below error from tesseract for an image of size 5+ MB.

Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
Page 0
Image too large: (39667, 56133)
Error during processing.

Is there a limit on file size or is there a parameter to resolve this issue.

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the file size but rather the image size (dimension) that exceeds Tesseract limits. I have no problems with Tesseract recognizing 16MB image. Try resize or rescale your image and try again.

Comment: thanks. are you aware of the maximum dimension allowed? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no specific values on the dimension limits. You may want to scour through its source code.

Comment: The answer below is far more detailed.

Answer (score 13):

The maximum width and height are 32767.

From the source code (file baseapi.cpp):

```
    if (tesseract_->ImageWidth() > MAX_INT16 ||
        tesseract_->ImageHeight() > MAX_INT16) {
      tprintf("Image too large: (%d, %d)\n",
              tesseract_->ImageWidth(), tesseract_->ImageHeight());
```