# Image too large error in tesseract

Tags: python

I am geeting image too large error while using tesseract for extracting text from image file in ubuntu 16.04 . Image size is 3.6 mb.is there any size limit for image file in tesseract.How can i resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's likely not the file size but the image size, ie pixels. Try scaling the image down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tesseract error - Image too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373116/tesseract-error-image-too-large)